# How to alert a view to show data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am new to angularjs. I just started creating a sample application. Please help me with your suggestions.

Below is my sample application.

[image: Sample application]

Below are the pages created:

1. page --> Notes.cshtml / notesController.js
2. NotesList --> NotesList.cshtml / notesListController.js
3. AddNote --> AddNote.cshtml / addNotecontroller.js
4. ViewNote --> ViewNote.cshtml / viewNoteController.js

When user select a note from the noteslist, i want to load details on the right side (in ViewNote.cshtml). Please note that i can show only Add Note or View Note at a time.Hence, i am using ng-show to show/hide respective partial controls.

***My question:***

1. When i click on a note from notes list, im calling server to fetch note details using a service.js. I understand that, the best way to share data b/w controllers is using a service. Hence, i kept the fetched data in service object.

   2. Now, i want to **intimate view.cshtml** to load the fetched data.
   3. Should i use $emit or $broadcast in **service.js** to intimate **ViewNoteController.js** ?
   4. I have service object injected into ViewNoteController.js

Is there a better way of handling this scenario? Please suggest.

Comment: This is a perfect scenario for ui states. You should use ui-router.https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: Thanks, I agree with you. I have implemented states now.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use $scope inside angular service instance so $emit or $broadcast will not work.

### You can use below solution:

### service.js

```
this.fetchData = function(url, successHandler, failureHandler) {
    $http.get(url).then(function(response) {successHandler(response);}, function() {});
}
```

### notesListController.js

```
function($scope, $rootScope, service) {

 $scope.loadList = function() {
    service.fetchData('someurl', fetchDataSuccessHandler, angular.noop);  
 }

 function fetchDataSuccessHandler(response) {
      var list = response.data;
      $rootScope.$broadcast('load-data', list);

 } 

}
```

### ViewNoteController.js

```
$scope.$on('load-data', function(event, list) {
    // add the code to load the view
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this.

Is this general practice in enterprise level apps? Generally, people try to avoid event propagation as far as possible right?

Comment: Correct but if you have a need to notify one to another then you will have to use it and this is the reason they have provided.